# How to use two array in one buffer with comptu shader(ssbo)?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

where struct in .cpp

`

```
struct {
   float data[Length];
   float convol[Length];
}inkernel;

DeviceSize deviceSize = sizeof(inkernel);

for (uint32_t i = 0;i < Length;i++)
{
    inkernel.convol[i] = 2;
    inkernel.data[i] = 3;

}

status = HPC::bvk::createBuffer(
    info.gpus[0],
    info.device,
    VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT,
    VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
    deviceSize,
    &inBuffer);
inBuffer.map();
memcpy(inBuffer.mapped, &inkernel, deviceSize);
inBuffer.unmap();`
```

the usage of two array in shader(with glsl)

`

```
layout (local_size_x = 4) in;
// Binding 0 : for test
layout(binding = 0) buffer In 
{
   float indata[];
   float cal[];
}inkernel;

layout(binding = 1) buffer Out 
{
   float outdata[];
}outkernel;


void main()
{   
   uint index = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
   outkernel.outdata[index] = inkernel.cal[index];
} `
```

through calculate,i read the data with outkernel.data,but the result is **3,not 2**.I don't why the inkernel.cal's values were changed to **3,not 2**.

Answer (score 0):

The values don't have to be in the same ssbo.

```
layout(binding = 0) buffer In 
{
   float indata[];
}inkernel1;
layout(binding = 1) buffer In 
{
   float cal[];
}inkernel2;

layout(binding = 2) buffer Out 
{
   float outdata[];
}outkernel;
```

Buffer is still the same, you only need to adjust the descriptors.